# ajax implementation in case where only jsp files are using for server code also instead of servlets?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

is it possible to implement ajax page loading for filling data to content div's when am working only with jsp files..?here am written the server side code also in jsp files instead of using servlets..how can i implement this...any help with some sample code...
thanks ..Tijo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is exactly the same. For the URL you pass the url of the jsp. The jsp is compiled to a servlet by the container, so no difference.